# search for directories containing one file and missing another

Tags: files, find

I am currently aware of how to search directories and list those which do NOT contain a specific file like so:

```
find parent_directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -i -q "^file_name$"' \; -print
```

but now I want to use the resulting directories to check whether or not they DO contain another file but I can't manage to do that in an extended one-line expression. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making this far more complicated than needed. You don't seem to want to recurse into subdirectories, so all you need to find those directories that don't have a specific file is:

```
for dir in */; do [ ! -e "$dir"/"$filename" ] || printf '%s\n' "$dir"; done
```

And, to see which of those do have another file:

```
for dir in */; do 
    [ ! -e "$dir"/"$filename1" ] && 
    [ -e "$dir"/"$filename2" ] && 
    printf '%s\n' "$dir"; 
done
```

Or, in a slightly clearer syntax:

```
for dir in */; do 
    if [ ! -e "$dir"/"$filename1" ]; then 
        if [ -e "$dir"/"$filename2" ]; then 
            printf '%s\n' "$dir"; 
        fi 
    fi
 done
```

This is all done using the built-in tools of the shell. Specifically:

- `[` : this, and the accompanying `]` are synonyms for the `test` builtin (see `help [` or `help test` if using an sh-style shell). They are ways of writing test operations in the shell.
- `-e` : this tests whether a file/directory etc exists. See `help test`. The simple format is: `[ -e file ]` which will return true if `file` exists.
- `[ ! -e filename ]` : the `!` simply inverses the test. So `[ ! -e file ]` will be true if `file` does **not** exist.

Taken together, this means the command above does:

```sh
## Iterate over every directory (dirs only because of the '/' in '*/')
## saving each of them in the variable $dir.
for dir in */; do 
    ## If this $dir does not contain $filename1
    if [ ! -e "$dir"/"$filename1" ]; then 
        ## If this $dir does contain $filename2
        if [ -e "$dir"/"$filename2" ]; then 
            ## Print the directory name
            printf '%s\n' "$dir"; 
        fi 
    fi
done
```

To run this, of course, you need to first set `$filename1` and `$filename2` accordingly. For example:

```
filename1="unwantedFile"
filename2="wantedFile"
```

Comment: @uitty400 please see update. Is that clear? You can also run `help test` on your machine for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid my comment was stupid so I deleted it. But your explanation helps a lot!

Comment: @uitty400 it is *never* stupid to ask for clarification!

Comment: Note that contrary to `find`'s `-type d`, the shell's `*/` also includes symlinks to directories and excludes hidden directories. Use `zsh` and `*(ND/)` instead to have a closer equivalent to `find`'s approach.

Comment: What if you want to find folders that contains only *.srt, but nothing else?

Comment: @Freedo please ask a new question. That's a very different problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can determine your required directories the following manner also:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -path '*/*/wanted.txt' -type f \
  -execdir test ! -f unwanted.txt \; -execdir pwd \;
```

How this works is as follows:

- We look for entries till the depth of 2.
- The `-path` option will further constrain them to be exactly a depth of 2 due to the presence of 2 slashes as the maxdepth precludes from going any further and 2 explict slashes prevent from going under depth of 2.
- The wanted.txt entry found at the depth level of 2 better be a regular file ensured by `-type f`
- The `-execdir` option will elevate the operation to the directory in which the wanted.txt resides and hence the `test` command will be looking for the unwanted file there.
- Next it is a simple matter of printing the directory (elevated due to `-execdir`) where the unwanted file was not found.
- Without meaning to belabor this point, a directory can contain a particular file just once, hence the `-execdir` operations are run once / directory and only on those directories that are at least sure to contain wanted.txt regular files.

Comment: I like @terdon's answer very much, but since I asked for how to do it with `find` in a one-liner I will accept this answer as the chosen solution.

Comment: @uitty400 terdon's answer is actually a 1-liner, it's not written that way. `for d in */; do [ ! -e "$d/notwant" ] && [ -e "$d/want" ] && echo "$d"; done`. Plus that method is very clear & direct. You may want to rethink your decision...

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`, to list the directories in the current directory that contain a `musthave` file and not a `mustnothave` file:

```
contain() [[ -e $REPLY/$1 || -L $REPLY/$1 ]]

printf '%s\n' *(D/e(contain musthave)^e(contain mustnothave))
```

Note that doing:

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'ls {}' \;
```

is not only not portable but is also a command injection vulnerability. For instance, if there's a directory called `$(reboot)` or `;reboot`, that would run the `ls $(reboot)` or `ls ;reboot` command lines causing a reboot. `{}` should never be embedded in a code argument (of `sh` or any other language) where it may be misinterpreted. Use:

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'ls "$1"' sh {} \;
```

instead.